# Pandas convert mongodb bson.tz_util.FixedOffset to standard date

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I am trying to calculate offset from epoch seconds with a Pandas dataframe created from data from a mongodb document.

An example of the data layout and operation is as per below (this codes works OK)

```
data = {'ds': ['2018-01-13 18:47:05.069722+00:00', '2018-01-14 18:47:05.119994+00:00', '2018-01-15 18:47:05.178768+00:00'], 
        'y': [38, 20, 26]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ds', 'y']) 
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
t = np.array(
                    (df['ds'] - pd.datetime(1970, 1, 1))
                    .dt.total_seconds()
                    .astype(np.float)
                ) / (3600 * 24.)
```

Note that however the dtype of the ds column in the code above is

```
datetime64[ns]
```

and the dtype of the date column from the actual pandas data in question is

```
datetime64[ns, <bson.tz_util.FixedOffset objec...
```

The only way I have been able to work out how to get around this is to convert to string then back to date:

```
dates = df['ds'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(dates)
```

Is there a better way to convert a

```
datetime64[ns, <bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object
```

into a datetime64[ns] column type in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd

# have to convert the series to date index
dsIndex = pd.Index(df['ds'])

# strip off the TZ info (assume it was <bson.tz_util.FixedOffset objec...)
dsIndex = dsIndex.tz_localize(tz=None)

# Reassign it to UTC
dsUTC = dsIndex.tz_localize(tz='UTC')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytz

df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: x.astimezone(pytz.utc))
```

does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant way is to specify the timezone in the pymongo connection directly.
This avoids pre-processings.

```
import pymongo
from bson.codec_options import CodecOptions

conn = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
codec_options = CodecOptions(tz_aware=True, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
database = conn.get_database().with_options(codec_options=codec_options)

db_aware_times.find_one({'name': 'test'})
```

Result :

```
{
    'name': 'test',
    'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 25, 10, 28, 34, 969000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
}
```